# Is there a way to group values based on remaining position?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, calculated-columns

I have different trades that I want to group by **Entry** date and **Symbol**.

This is the Origin Data: (these are all values I get from the User)

```
Date        Time       Symbol     Ordertype    Price     Shares (Note for you)
01/01/20    09:30:00   ABC        B            $5.00     500    (Day Trade)
01/01/20    10:30:00   ABC        S            $7.00     500    (Day Trade)
02/01/20    15:00:00   XYZ        B            $10.00    250    (Multi Day Trade)
04/01/20    10:00:00   XYZ        S            $20.00    250    (Multi Day Trade)
...
```

This is the Goal:  (Entry Date = first order day)

```
EntryDate   Symbol     Profit     TotalShares   Type
01/01/20    ABC        1000.00    1000          Day Trade
02/01/20    XYZ        2500.00    500           Multi Day Trade
```

As I also have MULTI-DAY Trades (where the order date is different) I can not group by "Date";

I thought about adding a calculated column like "remaining Position" or something in this direction ...

As I am relatively new to advanced SQL I hope someone can share his thoughts on this ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select EntryDate, Symbol,
       sum(case when ordertype = 'B' then - shares * price
                when ordertype = 'S' then shares * price
                else 0
           end) as Profit,
       TotalShares, Type
from t
group by EntryDate, Symbol, TotalShares, Type
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seams as if I did not wrote my case clearly - I used "()" in my origin data table to indicate it as a note for your reference => it's not a real value I have in my table ;) <br> Also do I only have orderdate in the origin table but the goal is to find the date of the first order of the trade and display it as "EntryDate"

Comment: @Dorbin4 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you intended to ask a different question, then ask a *new* question with the sample data that really expresses what you have and an explanation of the logic that you really want to implement.